# Unable to run firefox protractor without setting direct connect to false

Tags: angularjs, angular, protractor, protractor-net

I am attempting to run my unit tests in both chrome and firefox. Chrome runs all the test cases perfectly but I was unable to get firefox to run. To solve this problem I set directConnect to false as outlined here, https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4240

Firefox now runs but because directConnect is false it runs very slowly and fails most unit tests. In addition, chrome will no longer run.

When directConnect is set to true firefox gives me,
Unable to parse new session response: .....
WebDriverError: Unable to parse new session response:  .......

I'm using,
firefox 62.0.3
and protractor 5.4.0 with selenium standalone server

Comment: try to update web-drivers execute: node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update

Comment: Protractor 5.4.1 and firefox 62.0.3 64 bit work on my Mac with `directConnect: true`

Comment: Thanks, I updated webdriver-manager and geckodriver and selenium standalone server. Everything works now and directConnect can now be set to true. Cheers!